# How do I link a navbar item to a particular section in home page in bootstrap?

Tags: html, hyperlink, navbar, bootstrap-5, sections

I am trying to design a website for our client. In this website, I wish to make the "service" navbar item to a particular content area on the home page. For example, suppose if a user clicks on the "services" link then it moves to a particular section called "Our product" on the homepage. I have no idea how to achieve this....someone please help me! (I am using Bootstrap, Html, and CSS).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #314B1F;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img src="images/20220721_005023.png" alt="" width="30" height="24">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SAMKAY GLOBAL</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-end mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="about.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html#PROJECT_CASE">Services</a>

          </li>


          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Products
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Window System</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Door System</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Aluminum Partitions</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Curtain Walls</a></li>
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>Protected window System</li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sliding Window System</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Swing Window System</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">News/Event</a>
          </li>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>


        </ul>
        <img src="images/Facebook_Logo.png" alt="Facebook logo" width="30" height="24">
        <img src="images/whatsapp-logo-light-green-png-0.png" alt="Whatsapp logo" width="30" height="24">



      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

You have to link `href` with the `id` of the section you want to scroll to.

See the snippet below.

```css
#first-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}

#second-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#third-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}

#fourth-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#first-section">First section</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#second-section">Second section</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#third-section">Third section</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#fourth-section">Fourth section</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="first-section">First section</div>
<div id="second-section">Second section</div>
<div id="third-section">Third section</div>
<div id="fourth-section">Fourth section</div>
```

Comment: I am still somehow confuse with your answer, can you please explain better

Comment: Thanks so much Cervus, i have gotten it right now. Thumbs up

Comment: You have to link `href` with an `id` of the section you want to scroll to. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the explanation.